# LINQ to Entities Select taking a long time

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a `People` table with around 1000 rows and a `Dramas` table with around 100 rows in SQL Azure. The two are linked with a foreign key `Drama.PersonId` so that each person can have 0 or more dramas.

The code below behaves as expected, returning around 50 people and their associated recent dramas. However, it takes more than 5 seconds to run (measured with a `Stopwatch`). There must be something inefficient going on?

```
var people = ctx.People
  .Where(p => p.Dramas.Any(d => d.DateHappened >= startDate))
  .Select(p => new
    {
      p.FirstName,
      p.LastName,
      Dramas = p.Dramas.Where(d => d.DateHappened >= startDate).Select(d => new { d.Id, d.DramaType })
    }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: try lazy loading that might help!

Comment: I need all the information in the next line of my code so I don't think lazy loading would solve anything!

Comment: then try to run raw sql query .  http://forums.asp.net/t/1896474.aspx  check it out might help you!

Comment: How about turning the query around and first finding the dramas that match the search criteria and then finding the people associated with each of those dramas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made this much faster by first fetching all recent dramas and then sending a separate query to get the people. It uses a [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

```
var dramasByPerson = ctx.Dramas.Where(d => d.DateHappened >= startDate)
  .Select(d => new { d.PersonId, d.Id, d.DramaType })
  .ToLookup(d => d.PersonId);

var predicate = dramasByPerson.Select(o => o.Key)
  .Aggregate(
    PredicateBuilder.False<Person>(),
    (current, personId) => current.Or(o => o.PersonId == personId)
  );

var dictPeople = ctx.People.Where(predicate)
  .Select(o => new { o.PersonId, o.LastName, o.FirstName })
  .ToDictionary(o => o.PersonId);

var people = dramasByPerson.Select(o => new {
  LastName = people[o.Key].LastName,
  FirstName = people[o.Key].FirstName,
  Dramas = o.Select(d => new { d.Id, d.DramaType })
});
```